# Python incorrectly encoding bytecode into bytes

Tags: python, encoding, byte

I've been working on a project which compares bytecode generated from user input to bytecode on a server. Currently, the front-end is a CLI, written in python. The application simply opens the bytecode file on the user's local machine and compares it against bytecode coming from a server. This is what some of the code looks like:

```py
correct_data = requests.get(api endpoint).content
usr_data = open(bytecode file).read().encode('UTF-8')

if correct_data == usr_data:
    print("Good!")
```

Since the file reads in a string format, I encode the string into UTF-8 to compare it against the contents from the server. The server bytecode looks something like this:

10
0
6
1
2
6
1
3
6
1
4
6
1
5
6
1
6
6
1
7
6
1
8
6
1
9
6
1
10
6
1
11
6
1
12
6
1
13
6
1
14
6
1
15
1
2
4
0
8
3

This bytecode is correct. But, when I try to open and encode the same bytecode file from the local machine...

10
0
6
1
2
6
1
3
6
1
4
6
1
5
6
1
6
6
1
7
6
1
8
6
1
9
6
1
10
6
1
11
6
1
12
6
1
10
6
1
14
6
1
15
1
2
4
0
8
3

There is one very interesting change in this bytecode. What was supposed to be 6 1 13 becomes 6 1 10 and I can't seem to figure out why. I've made sure that these are the same exact files generated in the same way. This is an issue that consistently shows up. Any help would be amazing!

Comment: `13` is `\r` while 10 is `\n`. So the difference seems to be with how newlines are encoded.

Comment: @Barmar I see... there weren't any newlines in the original though, the bytecode for 6 1 13 represents a specific instruction in the bytecode. How do you think I could fix this behavior? Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: How are you creating the file on the local machine? You're probably using something that treats it as a text file and converts carriage return to newline.

Comment: @Barmar The code I am generating bytecode for is the Arduino superset of C. The way I'm generating it is by simply appending the user code to the end of the contents of a C++ file that takes the user code and generates a set of instructions in the form of a vector of uint8_t. I just take the data from the vector and store it in a file.

Comment: Make sure you open the file in `wb` mode, not `w`. On Windows, `w` mode will convert newlines.